# ReactRouter and react-create-app; how to render subcomponents by id?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to understand how I should use ReactRouter correctly in my current project. The project contains a dashboard with an overview and a possibility to open each item for editing. I'm trying to make it possible to navigate to specific items and rendering the editing view once user clicks the link.

The index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={App}/>
      <Route path="dashboard/:id" component={Editing}/>
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
    </div>
  </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The App component contains a container

```
import ItemContainer from './components/ItemContainer.js';
...
<div className='container'>
     <ItemContainer user={this.state.user} items={this.state.items} userProfile={this.state.userProfile}/>
</div>
```

The container maps the list of items to the dashboard depending on state of the container.

```
if(this.state.view === "editing"){
      return (
         <ItemEdit item={this.state.currentItem} uid={this.props.user.uid} 
         viewList={this.changeViewList.bind(this)}/>
      )}
if(this.state.view === "list"){
      return (
      this.props.items.map (item =>
            <li key={item.id}>
                <Item item={item} user={this.props.user} view={this.changeViewEditing.bind(this)}/>
            </li>
      ))}
```

Each item is rendered from item component that contains a button for changing to editing view

```
<div>
    <h3>
        {this.props.appName}
    </h3>
    <Link to={`/dashboard/${this.props.item.id}`}><button onClick={() => this.editItem(this.props.item)}>Edit</button></Link>
</div>
```

In the final block, the problem is of course that the link leads to empty url **dashboard/item:id**. From the examples I've been trying to understand how to configure this exactly, as the editing view is just a sub component of the App component. I have tried examples from ReactRouter website, but I'm unable to understand how to implement their examples in my context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`<Route path="/dashboard/:id" component={Editing}/>` - try this, maybe help

/ - may be you miss this symbol

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Though for me only 5 components were required so I used a switch case, but you can understand the basic principle.

```
class TestComponent implements Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
   }
     renderComponent(){

        switch(this.props.params.Id){
           case 1: return (<Component1/>); 
                   break;
           case 2: return (<Component2/>); 
                    break;
           case 3: return (<Component3/>); 
                    break;
           default: return(<div></div>);
                    break;

       }
     }
       render(){
          return(<div>{this.renderComponent()}</div>);
      }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I think I should probably change to the switch structure, but does this fix the Router problem? I'm probably missing something here; the main problem is that when I render the App>Container>Item:id in Editing view, the page is blank, because the Router in the index.js does not know what to render. My aim is that it would render the App with the editing state pointing to something like /dashboard/id:3243414

Comment: switch works if you have a separate url rather than an Id